# Allow IIS serving selected static files through ASP.NET pipeline

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

In my project we change one image depending on domain which was requested. Of course we can serve different files (css, js, html), but much more easy is to handle this one file and serve user correct one (let's call it `logo.ico`)

In web.config we set `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">` which causes that that IIS serve all static files for us.

Is there a way to add exception for `logo.ico' file?

To make example clear: when browser request http://mydomian.com/logo.ico I would like to run custom handler. For every other file I would like to use IIS native solution (which means `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">`)

Comment: Hi @Piotr if you are using MVC then you can add routing for logo.ico and reroute to specific controller.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to add exception just for one file, but you could serve that image with ashx handler, for example url should look like (add your own logic to select image)

http://mydomian.com/ServeImage.ashx?image=logo.ico

And then just serve icon for that domain:

```
  public class ServeImage : IHttpHandler
  {

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
      context.Response.ContentType = "image/x-icon";
      using (var fs = new FileStream(context.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/logo.ico"), FileMode.Open))
      {
        fs.CopyTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
      }      
    }


    public bool IsReusable
    {
      get
      {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
```